# How do I programatically query the current memory settings of Apache TomCat7 on Windows?

Tags: apache, tomcat, chef-infra

We use chef to install and configure our software.

I want to add a configuration to Tomcat to change the memory settings.

If I just add this to the configuration now, it will continue to add and add and add each time it is run.

According to this article, you can do this on the command line using something like this:

```
tomcat6 //US//Tomcat6 --JvmMx 1024 ++JvmOptions="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

we're using tomcat7, so we've changed it to:

```
tomcat7 //US//Tomcat7 --JvmMx 1024 ++JvmOptions="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

There's a mention of using tomcat6 //ES/Tomcat6 to query.

I was hoping it would output it to std out, but it does not.

Is there somewhere I can programatically check for the current settings so I don't add it back again and again.

Potential answers don't have to be Chef specific, just the command line would be good.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

The usual "programmatic" way to accomplish this would be via JMX, but since you said:

> just the command line

You can use reg.exe to get the Java parameters for the service that are stored in the Registry:

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\<TOMCAT_SERVICE_NAME>\Parameters\Java"
```

This will dump all the Java parameters, and in your case, you're looking for "JvmMx".

Comment: For 64-bit it is slightly different: `reg query "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\<TOMCAT_SERVICE_NAME>\Parameters\Java"`

Answer (score 0):

In commons-procrun v1.2.3, a [new command](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DAEMON-422) has been added to the list: print-config

You can run it like this:

```
tomcat7 //PS//Tomcat7
```

and it will dump-out the existing configuration for you.

This was added to Tomcat 7.0.106, and the next versions of Tomcat 8.5 and Tomcat 9.0 should also have it when they are next released. (The back-ports have been done; just waiting on a release.)